GSI is not updated in unit testcases using local dynamodb
GET Groups/{id} is supposed to return members belonging to that group also in the response body, so it has to query the database using GSI, but in my unit testcases, since I'm using local dynamodb, for a unit test case where the members of the group has to be fetched, GSI is not updated and querying the members from the database is failing, so can anyone help me with this
I tried writing group data into group table and added members and also tried writing user group mapping data into user-group-mapping-table, and then the code goes as to fetch the members from the group from the table using GSI, but shows zero members, so I doubt there could be no update in GSI and hence it failing

We probably need a simple code example. Are you saying that the code successfully retrieves data from the database under other normal circumstances but not when unit tests? What unit test framework are you using?
